# C++ SQL project to query internal data structures

Tags: c++, sql, in-memory-database

I have a C++ class:

```
class Car {

 string name; //name of the car
 int year; // year it was made
 string color; //an int representing color
 int price;  // how much does it cost
 string country; // country of origin
 etc...

};
```

The class is part of a server process that takes input and creates instances of this class.

- ("bmw", "2015", "red", 30000, "DE")
- ("fiat", "2014", "green", 20000, "IT")
- ("ford", "2012", "white", 21000, "USA")
- ("citroen", "2011", green", 15000, "FR")

That instances are my in memory car database. So my question is:
Is there any general purpose SQL C++ project that takes as input the car-db and a query string and returns results?

For example "select * from mydata where color=green and price>10000", should return a "pointer" to the second and fourth elements.

Comment: Do you want ready made solution or an advice on making one?

Comment: @KillzoneKid ready made

Comment: Ready made would be off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @drescherjm then a non ready made

Comment: It's still off-topic if you're asking for a link to an off-site resource.If you're wanting it posted here then your request is too broad based on your lack of effort to produce any code to do what you're asking us to provide to you.

Comment: Hint: a pointer points at one point, 2 _or_ 4, it can't point at 2 _and_ 4. You are looking for a structure, a set of data. Look into `Datareader`, or `DataTable` (DataSet)

Comment: @marlan does the DataTable belong to a library? boost?

Comment: [Look what I found on Google!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @marlan, thanks but the project runs on Linux.

Comment: oops... why did I see C#...? My fault! Iv'e never done it from C++. I Googled _linux c++ database tutorial_, and got a few nice results. Try it, it should work for you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right you're looking for a relational database supporting in-memory data handling and SQL?

In this case you should look at [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/about.html), which implements [In-Memory Databases](http://sqlite.org/about.html) and a [decent](http://sqlite.org/fullsql.html), [reasonably standard-compliant](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) [SQL subset](https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html). It provides a [C-style API](http://sqlite.org/cintro.html) out of the box, is well done and widely used.

For C++ APIs you can look at [Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/topics-data-storage.html#sql-support-in-qt), if that's an option for your use case, or search for an [ORM](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sqlite+orm+c%2B%2B) that fits your requirements. Even implementing your own OO wrapper around a DB handle is an option (been there, done that).